# Playwright equivalent for JavaScript's "closest" function

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I'm using Playwright, which lacks an equivalent for JavaScript's `closest()` function.

Can I accomplish that using XPath?

Comment: Playwright lets you run JS in the browser, so you can use `.closest()` in an `evaluate()` block--it won't auto-wait but you can use `waitForFunction` or similar if necessary. XPath is possible as well, but generally discouraged. What are you trying to accomplish that necessitates `.closest()`? There may be a better way to do it if you don't mind providing context.

Comment: @ggorlen I know about `evaluate`, but I specifically wanted to avoid it, thus I asked for xpath. Regarding context: I often need something like `closest` during scraping, yet it does not exist in the Playwright API. The auto waiting with xpath is nice.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `evaluate`? That's not much context--the fact that you often need `.closest()` is surprising--I manipulate pages constantly and don't find I need it often, so with more context I can [probably provide a better way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: The reason `.closest()` is a possible antipattern is that, generally speaking, you should scrape top-down rather than traversing up the tree, which sort of defeats the purpose of trees, which let you work with one root to isolate many children. Select parent containers, then dive into children, rather than selecting children and traversing back up. Same thing with XPath, you really shouldn't need it 99% of the time.

Comment: @ggorlen I agree with your general sentiment about html design and traversal. But... you are assuming the page was written by someone with experience - yet some pages I scrape have many many problems, with multiple ids, missing classes/ids, divs for everything, etc. In some of those cases it's **impossible** to traverse downward to my element of interest, but if I'm lucky there is a way I can isolate an element lower in the tree and traverse upward to its parent, or to a sibling, etc. Web scraping is messy, there is no "right way", you need to deal with what you get.

Comment: @ggorlen BTW, I also avoid XPath whenever possible - but it's an excellent tool in some cases, and I can't imagine doing web scraping without it. My answer below packages it cleanly in an API that should have been included in Playwright natively.

Comment: Of course, there are rare times to use `.closest()`, but if you show me the page, I'd like to think I can show a way to avoid it. This self-answer style question is missing a key point, the practical problem motivating it. There should be context, a real, ["practical, answerable"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) problem you're solving. Documenting random ideas/tidbits in Q&A format feels off-topic.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but disagree. I often need `closest()`, and each time search for "how", but never find anything. So I decided to post it myself for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the .NET bindings, but you can convert the following to your environment.

I defined extension methods (input validation excluded for brevity):

```cs
public static ILocator Closest(this ILocator locator, string className) =>
  locator.Locator($"//ancestor::*[contains(@class, '{className}')]");

public static ILocator Closest(this ILocator locator, string attributeName, string valueName) =>
  locator.Locator($"//ancestor::*[contains(@{attributeName}, '{valueName}')]");

public static ILocator Closest(this ILocator locator, string elementName, string attributeName, string valueName) =>
  locator.Locator($"//ancestor::{elementName}[contains(@{attributeName}, '{valueName}')]");
```

Which are used like so:

```cs
var closestByClass               = myLocator.Closest("foo");
var closestByAttribute           = myLocator.Closest("title", "Click this to do foo");
var closestByElementAndAttribute = myLocator.Closest("div", "data-account-balance", "42");
```

There are some edge cases, but it works for my use case.

Comment: js closest returns 0 or 1 object.
Your xpath's could return more than one.
Therefore beter xpath's would be to add the predicate `[1]` to the end. This will stop at the first ancestor it finds.
So your first xpath would look like: 
`//ancestor::*[contains(@class, '{className}')][1]`

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed That is a good point. I think some people will want to use [0]. In my case I avoided it because Playwright locators can refer to one or more elements, so I wanted it to work like other playwright locators.